# Array - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, array

Estoy empezando a aprender JavaScript, pero me temo que me eh estancado en esta parte.
Entiendo la idea de este código, pero no entiendo el funcionamiento a su totalidad, agradecería alguna explicación.

```
function reverseArrayInPlace(array) {  
    for (let i = 0; i < Math.floor(array.length / 2); i++) {  
      let old = array[i];  
      array[i] = array[array.length - 1 - i];  
      array[array.length - 1 - i] = old;  
    }
    return array;  
  }

let arrayValue = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];  
reverseArrayInPlace(arrayValue);  
console.log(arrayValue);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que tienes ahi es un algoritmo, una forma bastante eficiente de realizar un `reverse` a los elementos de un `array`:

```js
function reverseArrayInPlace(array) {
  for (let i = 0; i < Math.floor(array.length / 2); i++) {
    let old = array[i];
    array[i] = array[array.length - 1 - i];
    array[array.length - 1 - i] = old;
  }
  
  return array;
}

let arrayValue = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

reverseArrayInPlace(arrayValue);
console.log(arrayValue);
```

Me explico, existe la funcion `reverse` la cual hace exactamente lo mismo:

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    arr.reverse();
    
console.log(arr);
```

Sin embargo si quisieramos hacer un proceso manual mucha gente lo que haria seria algo como lo siguiente:

```js
function reverse(arr)
{
  for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
  {
    const temp = arr[i];
    arr[i] = arr[arr.length - 1 - i];
    arr[arr.length - 1 - i] = temp;
  }
  
  return arr;
}

const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
console.log(reverse(arr));
```

Y para ellos tendria sentido ese codigo, sin embargo como vemos no nos da el resultado esperado (el arreglo resultado no cambia y es igual al original aparentemente).

Precisamente por esto es que vemos en tu codigo la siguiente instruccion:

```
i < Math.floor(array.length / 2)
```

Y es que esta condicion es **clave** para que no hagamos un doble **reverse** sin querer pues si nos fijaramos detalladamente en que es lo que esta pasando, lo que ocurre es que al llegar a la mitad o antes de la mitad de las iteraciones de todo el array, ya nuestro proceso teoricamente ha terminado.

Pero si siguieramos ejecutando el proceso usando todos los espacios en memoria del array, tecnicamente estariamos primero revirtiendo el arreglo una vez y luego volviendolo a revertir:

```js
function reverse(arr)
{
  for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
  {
    const temp = arr[i];
    arr[i] = arr[arr.length - 1 - i];
    arr[arr.length - 1 - i] = temp;
    
    if(i === 1 || i === arr.length - 1)
    {
      console.log(arr);
    }
  }
  
  return arr;
}

const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
reverse(arr);
```

Como vemos, y como habiamos dicho, primero lo revertimos y luego lo volvemos a revertir, quedando como en un inicio.

En terminos tecnicos, llegamos a la conclusion de que entonces **NO** podemos usar de manera directa el tamaño completo del array para realizar un `reverse` a un `array` pues si usasemos el tamaño completo de un `array` ocurriria que revertiriamos dos veces el array, dandonos un resultado inesperado.

Con esto podemos sacar otra conclusion muy importante, y es que analizando el como funciona el algoritmo, deducimos que nada mas hace falta llegar a la mitad o menos de la mitad del recorrido completo del array para hacer un `reverse`, haciendo el proceso incluso mas eficiente.

Entonces ya llegados a este punto te explicare mas detalladamente lo que esta pasando en tu codigo.

```
for (let i = 0; i < Math.floor(array.length / 2); i++)
```

En esta parte se declara un ciclo que va desde el primer elemento del array hasta la mitad entera mas cercana del array, ej:

si tuviesemos un arreglo de 5 espacios el resultado de `Math.floor(array.length / 2)` debe ser `2` pues `Math.floor` redondea hacia abajo:

```js
const array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

console.log(Math.floor(array.length / 2));
```

Entonces recordemos que el ciclo nunca recorrera el arreglo completo, solo recorrera la mitad o menos de la mitad (ya que es lo unico que hace falta y seria erroneo realizar el proceso hasta el final).

```
  //Guardamos el elemento actual del arreglo en una variable old
  let old = array[i];
  /*
     Al elemento actual del array lo reemplazamos con el ultimo
     elemento del array menos i
  */
  array[i] = array[array.length - 1 - i];

  //Reemplazamos el ultimo elemento del array menos i por el valor old
  array[array.length - 1 - i] = old;
```

Esto en otros terminos si lo analizamos bien significa que cogera el primer valor del array y lo reemplazara con el valor del ultimo elemento del array.

Luego cogera el segundo valor del array y lo reemplazara con el penultimo valor del array.

Para este caso en especifico con 2 iteraciones basta, por lo que ahi concluye el ciclo, y al hacer el proceso tendremos lo siguiente:

```
//Arreglo original
1 2 3 4 5

//1era iteracion
5 2 3 4 1

//Segunda y ultima iteracion
5 4 3 2 1
```

Concluyendo entonces de manera mas grafica y entendible lo que esta pasando, pues enrealidad es como si mataramos dos pajaros de un tiro, ya que ordenamos de manera rapida y eficiente con menos iteraciones de las que tiene el propio arreglo.